# How can I post pass data without specifying each variable in Typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, interface

I have an interface which I use in component, but how can i pass all this data by one props like mainInfo = {User} without specifying each variable. I don't want done object inside Inteface for all data.
User is an object whith different information.

Interface

```
export interface MainInfo {
  id: number;
  firstName: string;
  lastName: string;
  age: number;
  country: string;
  speaks: Languages[];
  learn: Languages[];
  isOnline: boolean;
  isFriend: number;
  photoUrl: string;
}
```

Component where I use Interface

```
import { MainInfo } from '../../interfaces/Interface';

export const UserCard: React.FC<MainInfo> = ( mainInfo ) => {
```

How I pass props

```
      <UserCard
        id={User.id}
        firstName={User.firstName}
        lastName={User.lastName}
        age={User.age}
        country={User.country}
        speaks={User.speaks}
        learn={User.learn}
        isOnline={User.isOnline}
        isFriend={User.isFriend}
        photoUrl={User.photoUrl}
      />
```

but can i do something like this ?

```
      <UserCard
        mainInfo={User}
      />
```

Comment: Yes, you can do exactly that, just change the props type to `{ mainInfo: MainInfo }`. Or just spread the user object, `<UserCard {...User} />`.

Answer (score 0):

```
   interface MainInfo {
      id: number;
      firstName: string;
      lastName: string;
      age: number;
      country: string;
      speaks: Languages[];
      learn: Languages[];
      isOnline: boolean;
      isFriend: number;
      photoUrl: string;
    }
    export interface IProps {
      mainInfo: MainInfo;
    }


import { IProps } from '../../interfaces/Interface';

export const UserCard: React.FC<IProps> = ( mainInfo ) => {
```

Comment: I would argue the props type belongs with the component, not the model.

Answer (score 0):

This is not TypeScript specific. What you're looking for is [JSX spread attributes](https://zhenyong.github.io/react/docs/jsx-spread.html) that work like this:

```
<UserCard {...User} />
```